# can I force user to update my app using hockeyapp?

Tags: ios, app-store, hockeyapp

I've got an iOS app. Currently it's being distributed to tester users.
I'm about ready to publish the app to the Appstore. 
I'm interested in a case where there is a newer version of the app in the Appstore.

Does hockeyapp have any built-in functionality to prompt the user to update the application, and prevent him from using it until updated?

Comment: We recommend to use the support system for HockeyApp related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check

> BITStoreUpdateManager

```
The store update manager module.

 This is the HockeySDK module for handling app updates when having your app released in the App Store.
 By default the module uses the current users locale to define the app store to check for updates. You
 can modify this using the `countryCode` property. See the property documentation for details on its usage.

 When an update is detected, this module will show an alert asking the user if he/she wants to update or
 ignore this version. If update was chosen, it will open the apps page in the app store app.

 You need to enable this module using `[BITHockeyManager enableStoreUpdateManager]` if you want to use this
 feature. By default this module is disabled!

 When this module is enabled and **NOT** running in an App Store build/environment, it won't do any checks!

 The `BITStoreUpdateManagerDelegate` protocol informs the app about new detected app versions.

 @warning This module can **NOT** check if the current device and OS version match the minimum requirements of
 the new app version!
```

reference: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios#storeupdates

Answer (score 4):

Using HockeyApp there is a checkbox to prompt users for a mandatory update to the current app if there is a newer build available.

[image: Update]

Comment: Would this be included in the Appstore version?

Comment: Also where is this option specified, can't find it :(

Comment: The update functionality is automatically disabled in your AppStore version, since that couldn't work there. So this only works for beta versions. You can find the feature under the app version that you want the users to update to, click "Manage Version" and then "Status".

Comment: Where are those radio buttons? Can't find them.

Answer (score 2):

You can force beta users to update to a newer app version, but you can **not** force App Store users to update to a newer app version!

The SDK provides a feature to notify users from your App Store builds about new updates, but there is no way to force those to upgrade. This feature is documented here: http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.6.2/Classes/BITStoreUpdateManager.html

Comment: Can the user still use the older version in the appstore scenario?

Comment: Yes, as I said, you can *not* force a user to update in the AppStore scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [appgrades.io](https://appgrades.io) to force users to update their app when new versions are available on the AppStore.